# How to remove duplicate from string and then produce a comma separated values with single quotes in php

Tags: php, arrays, string

How i can remove duplicate from this string and then produce a comma separated values with single quotes to later use IN('1','2') query.

```
$str=1,1,2,2,2,;
```

And i want this

```
$str ='1','2';
```

This is what i have tried so far.

```
$string = rtrim($str,',');
$result = implode(",", array_unique(explode(',', $string)));
echo'<pre>';print_r($result);
```

produced result:

```
1,2
```

Comment: `$result = implode("','", array_unique(explode(',', $string)));`

Comment: thank you for the answer,it produce {1','2},so start quotes are missing

Comment: `$str=1,1,2,2,2,;` isn't even a valid variable assignment.

Comment: simple add `'` at end of your string.

Answer (score 3):

This probably is what you are looking for:

```
<?php
$input = "1,1,2,2,2,";
$output = "'" . implode("','", array_unique(explode(',', trim($input, ',')))) . "'";
var_dump($output);
```

The output of above code is:

```
string(7) "'1','2'"
```

Comment: exactly this is what i was looking for,thank you @arkascha

Comment: Can you please tell me why i am getting "\" is query.
select * from `users` where `id` in ('\'1\',\'2\'')

Comment: You shouldn't escape that variable in the query @KhiradBanu - is it from user input? How do you get the string to begin with?

Comment: @KhiradBanu most likely you use something like `mysqli::real_escape_string()` or similar. You should not. You should use the combination of "prepared statements" and "parameter binding" to prevent sql injection attacks, not manual escaping.

Comment: I am not using any escape,i am getting this string form iterating a loop

Comment: @KhiradBanu Then you need to ask a separate question about that topic, posting your actual code performing that query. That is nothing that can be discussed or solved in comments and it actually is a separate issue.

Answer (score 2):

You just include the singlequotes in your glue in `implode()`. The glue is now `', '` instead of `,`. Then just prepend and append the quotes before and after.

```
$str = "1,1,2,2,2,";
$string = rtrim($str, ',');
$result = implode("', '", array_unique(explode(',', $string)));
$result = "'$result'";
```

The result is now

```
'1', '2'
```

[**Live demo**](https://3v4l.org/2MdSX)

Answer (score 1):

**Try this**

```
$str="1,1,2,2,2,";
echo $str = implode(',',array_unique(explode(',', trim($str, ","))));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use array_unique(), trim(), explode() and implode() function to incorporate this:

```
<?php
$str='1,1,2,2,2,';
$temp = explode(',', trim($str, ','));
$result = "'" . implode ( "', '", array_unique($temp)) . "'";
echo '<pre>';
print_r($result);
echo '</pre>';

// Outputs '1', '2'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution for your problem.

```
$str="1,1,2,2,2";
$string = rtrim($str,',');
$result = "'".implode("','", array_unique(explode(',', $string)))."'";
echo'<pre>';print_r($result);
```